# Shift column names to the left by 1 column

Tags: python, dataframe

What it looks like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kefkf.jpg.

What I need it to look like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yEa9Y.jpg

I imported the file as a tsv and converted it into a csv. After doing so, this is how I imported my data                                      `train = pd.read_csv('./gene_train.csv', sep ='\t')
train.shape`

Comment: Have you write some code?

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: Hi, could you please give some example-code and how the dataframe is structured? Because we don't know what you're working with, we can't be sure where the problem might be.

Comment: Post the first few lines of your csv and your code

Comment: Just posted!!!!

Comment: Is your CSV actually tab delimited? It looks like the header row has some delimiter characters within the column names.

Comment: Yes. I imported it from a tsv file and converted into csv so had to use the delimiter

Answer (score 1):

You did not show how your dataframe looks like. But in general, you can get a list of all column names of a dataframe by

```
colnames = list(train.columns)
```

and now you said it is shifted by +1 to the right. I assume it means data of column 1 should match `colnames[2]`. So you can re-assign the column name by:

```
train.columns = colnames[1:]
```

but, in this way, you will miss the "rightmost" or last column and you have to fix that.